# How to get max value from list of doubles that are less than an input value using IEnumerable.Max extensions

Tags: c#, max, ienumerable, extension-methods

I am trying to get the maximum value from a list of doubles, that are below a specific input value.
code:

```
List<double> tmpList = new List<double> { 1.2d, 2.8d, 3.4d, 0.4d, 6.3d };
double inputValue = 3.1d;
int countOfValuesBelowInput = tmpList.Count(z => z < inputValue); // this works
double maxBelowInput = tmpList.Max(z => z < inputValue); // compile error
```

I get a compile error on the last line - saying "Cannot implicitly convert bool to double". What am I not doing right? Appreciate any help and sorry if this is a duplicate - tried my best to google.

Comment: Try `tmpList.Where(z => z < inputValue).Max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the list by using [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) before you take the maximum like this:

```
double maxBelowInput = tmpList.Where(z => z < inputValue).Max();
```

The reason why your current code does not work is that the overload of `Max` you are using is expecting a *selector*, not a *predicate*.

A selector is a function that takes the item and outputs a related value, usually a property of the item. For example, if the list is of type `Person`, you could get the maximum age of the people by using `.Max(x => x.Age)`. Here you are *selecting* something from each element.

On the other hand, `Count` takes in a predicate, which is basically a filter. It is a function that takes the item and returns either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful.